# Running Behave Tests on Jenkins with Python

Tags: python, shell, jenkins

I have the BDD tests running locally on my Mac, but the `behave` command isn't recognized on Jenkins after installing the dependency. Here is the workflow:

Jenkinsfile installs all dependencies from `requirements.txt` file

```
sh 'pip-3.6 --no-cache-dir install --user -Ur requirements.txt'
```

The `requirements.txt` file contains

```
behave==1.2.6
```

Next, the Jenkinsfile runs all tests by running `behave`

**Error:**

```
behave: command not found
```

> Why does Jenkins not work with behave?

Comment: Can you import the package in Jenkins? Is there a Python version mismatch?

Comment: @KlausD. I can't import in Jenkins. To validate things, I ran `behave --version` directly after installing and it fails for the same reason.